# Xunit in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

I'm new at asp.net and moq and xunit test, I want to create a test case for my asp.net project. I have the service file that is CRUD action,

I have been written for Create Method it's Ok but at Get, GetAll, Delete, Put method I don't know what should I setup

```
public void Test1()
{
    var tutorRequest = new Mock<ITutorRequestService>();
    //What should i set up for Get and GetAll
    tutorRequest.Setup(r => r.Get(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string?>()))
       .ReturnsAsync(() => new Entity());
    var logger = new Mock<ILogger<TutorRequestsController>>();

    var controller = new TutorRequestsController(tutorRequest.Object, logger.Object);

    var rs =  controller.Get(1, "");
    Assert.NotNull(rs);
}
```

My service class

```
public async Task<TutorRequest> Create(TutorRequestModel tutor)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<TutorRequest>(tutor);
    CheckDataNotNull("entity", entity);
    entity = await _repository.Add(entity);
    return _mapper.Map<TutorRequest>(entity);
}

public async Task<TutorRequest> Delete(int tutorId)
{
    var entity = await _repository.Delete(tutorId);
    return _mapper.Map<TutorRequest>(entity);
}

public async Task<Entity> Get(int id, string? fields)
{
    var entity = await _repository.Get(id);

    CheckDataNotNull("tutor request", entity);
    var shaped = _dataShaper.ShapeData(entity, fields);
    CheckDataNotNull("shaped", shaped);

    return _mapper.Map<Entity>(shaped);
}

public PageList<Entity> GetAll(TutorRequestParams param)
{
    var listAll = _repository.GetAll();
    CheckDataNotNull("shaped", listAll);

    Search(ref listAll, param);

    var sortedStudent = _sortHelper.ApplySort(listAll, param.OrderBy);
    var shapedOwners = _dataShaper.ShapeData(sortedStudent, param.Fields);

    return PageList<Entity>.ToPageList(shapedOwners, param.PageNume, param.PageSize);
}

public async Task<TutorRequest> Update(TutorRequestModel tutor)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<TutorRequest>(tutor);
    entity = await _repository.Update(entity);
    return _mapper.Map<TutorRequest>(entity);
}
```

Comment: "I have tried But it seems like not correct" what led you to that conclusion?  What error are you getting?

Comment: You've made a Mock object, but do you know how to `Setup()` a method?

Comment: Also, I'm going to suggest you don't ever use `ExpandoObject` for a REST response object. You should always know the schema of a response at compile time.

Comment: I'm doing well with Create method but with Get, GetAll, Delete I'm don't how to Setup() method @gunr2171

Comment: At my Test1() method, It should return a TutorRequest with Id = 1 but it returns null. and I think my Setup() is not correct @KirkWoll

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting the `GetAll` method to return something, you need to set up the call for the mocked service.

```cs
mockRepo.Setup(r => r.GetAll(It.IsAny<TutorRequestParams>())).Returns(
  new PagedList<ExpandoObject>
  {
     // result you're expecting
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have write a test case for Get method that similar to your example, you can check it out

```
public void Test_Get_Method()
{
    var questService = new Mock<IQuestService>();
    questService.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<Guid>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new QuestResponseModel()
        {
            Id = Guid.Empty,
            Title = "Test",
            Description = "TestDescription",
            Price = 100,
            Status = "Pending",
            AvailableTime = DateTime.Now,
            EstimatedTime = "120",
            QuestTypeId = 1
        });

    var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();

    var controller = new QuestController(questService.Object);

    var result = controller.Get(Guid.Empty);

    Assert.Equal("TestDescription", result.Result.Data.Description);
}
```